# How to split a line by multiple characters?

Tags: string, split

Output of `w | head -1` can give 2 different results for my machine:

```
16:34:42 up 32 days,  3:02,  1 user,  load average: 0.14, 0.11, 0.07
14:10:55 up 32 days, 39 min, 1 user, load average: 0.07, 0.13, 0.09
```

I need to get load average numbers (e.g. `0.07, 0.13, 0.09`). How can I split the line by `load average:` string so that I can always get the load average numbers for two cases?

Comment: try this `awk 'print $10 $11 $12'`

Comment: Incidental tip: use `uptime` to get this information instead of `w | head -1`. It's more direct, you don't have to filter the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I'd just use the `${parameter#word}` [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  It expands `$parameter`, deleting `word` (which can be a pattern) from the start.

In your case, something like:

```
line=...
echo ${line#*load average: }
```

Making it a function:

```
get_load() {
    w | head -n 1 | { read -r line; echo ${line#*load average: }; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use awk:

```
$ w | head -1 | awk '{print $10,$11,$12}'
0.80, 0.84, 0.93
```

Or, if the number of fields is variable, use:

```
$ w | head -1 | awk '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
0.81, 0.82, 0.91
```

Or, the much more elegant ([thanks @Letitzia](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159470/how-to-split-a-line-by-multiple-characters/159486?noredirect=1#comment261286_159486)):

```
$ w | head -1 | awk -F "load average: " '{print $2}'
```

Sed:

```
$ w | head -1 | sed 's/.*load average: *//'
```

Perl:

```
$ w | head -1 | perl -pe 's/.*load average: *//'
```

or

```
$ w | head -1 | perl -lne '/.*load average: *(.*)/ && print $1'
```

You can actually use `colrm` here but note that it removes "columns" which are defined as "a single character in a line". So, while it works for the example you have provided (because of the extra space) it won't if the number of columns changes further. Here, it's deleting columns 1 through 51

```
$ w | head -1 | colrm 1 51
```

Comment: or `w | head -1 | awk -F "load average: " '{print $2}'`

Comment: @Letizia ooh, clever, I never think of setting FS to longer strings. Included in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Why you need `head -1`? `w | awk -F "load average: " '{print $2; exit}'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you're quite right, I don't. I was focusing on the parsing so I just copied the OP's exact command.

Comment: Oh, How `w | head -1` command would give two lines as output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it doesn't, it's just that at different times, the OP's output changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want only last numbers you can use grep:

```
$ w | grep -Po 'load average: \K.*'
0.07, 0.13, 0.09
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `perl`:

```
$ w | head -1 | perl -nle 'print +(split /load average:/)[-1]'
 0.42, 0.49, 0.63
```